# Loading content from a JSON / CSV and make the textbox fit to the content with basil.js

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I'm successfully loading a JSON file into InDesign via basil.js.

```
var jsonString = b.loadString("data.json");
var jsonData;

function setup() {

  jsonData = b.JSON.decode(jsonString);

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    var myText = jsonData[i].text;
    b.text(myText, 100, 10 * i, 100, 20);
  };
}

b.go();
```

The result looks as expected:

[image: The result looks as expected:]
What I'd like to achieve is

1. That the text frames automatically fit their height to the content,
   smth. like `fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);`
2. That the textBoxes continue until the page bounds and then a new
   page is added.

Any hints are warmly appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

for your first problem

> That the text frames automatically fit their height to the content, smth. like fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);

you can just use `myText.fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);`. You don't have to stick with Basil if something is not implemented there.

> That the textBoxes continue until the page bounds and then a new page is added.

This is a little trickier. If you extend the textframes their size will change. You will need another variable outside of your loop that tracks the `geometricBounds` of the last frame and adds the next frame at the beginning of them. When your last bounds exceed the pageHeight you will need to add a new page.

This is something to get you started. It is untested code.

```
/**
 * InDesign Objects have a property called 
 * geometricBounds
 * these are the bounds in page coordinates sorted like this
 * [y1, x1, y2, x2]
 * or in words
 * [
 *   y of upper left corner, 
 *   x of upper left corner,
 *   y of lower right corner, 
 *   x of lower right corner
 * ]
 */
var prevGeometricBounds = [100, 10, 100, 10]; 
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  var myText = jsonData[i].text;
  var x = prevGeometricBounds[1];
  var y = prevGeometricBounds[0];
  var w = prevGeometricBounds[3] - prevGeometricBounds[1];
  var h = prevGeometricBounds[2] - prevGeometricBounds[1];
  var textFrame = text(myText, x, y, w, h);
  textFrame.fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
  prevGeometricBounds = myText.geometricBounds;
  if(prevGeometricBounds[2] > height){
    addPage();
  }
}
```

---

Another hint. As you can see I omitted the `b.` Basil evolved a lot but we did not yet release the version 2. You can grab the latest version from the [develop branch](https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/tree/develop) over at GitHub. The docs for that are located [here](https://basiljs2.netlify.com/).

---

Edit 1

In Basil 2 you should be able to load the JSON using [`loadString`](https://basiljs2.netlify.com/reference/input/loadstring) and then decode it using [JSON.parse](https://basiljs2.netlify.com/reference/data/json.parse)

The Basil text function returns a [`textFrame`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#TextFrame.html). So the `fit` function should work. If you run into bugs we are happy to accept bug reports over at [github](https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc).

---

Edit 2

The `fit` was called on the string you loaded from the JSON not on the result of the `text()` function.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Both approaches throw a no function error